# How can I do to select only one item in my react-multi-select-component?

Tags: reactjs, multi-select

I would like to choose only one option in my react-multi-select-component. Usually with other libraries I use `isOptionDisabled` but with that library the attribute is not valid.

Here is my code :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import MultiSelect from "react-multi-select-component";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const options = [
    { label: "Grapes ", value: "grapes" },
    { label: "Mango ", value: "mango" },
    { label: "Strawberry ", value: "strawberry" }
  ];

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div>
      <MultiSelect
        options={options}
        selected={selected}
        onChange={setSelected}
        labelledBy={"Select"}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

The project is there :

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-select-component-example-forked-9xjdpr?file=/src/index.js:0-666

My problem is that I am allowed to select multiple options and I want to be restricted to selecting only one of them.

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: what is the problem that you are seeing? ... `how can I do?` and `I would like to` are not descriptions of a problem

Comment: I want to select only one and not many items with that component.

Comment: I updated my problem

Comment: if you want to select one option then why are you using multiselect?

Comment: It is called ``react-multi-select`` exactly for that reason: To select multiple options. "Simple and lightweight multiple selection dropdown component"

Answer (score 0):

As i’ve just saw from the npm doc of react-multi-select-component, that you can add the attribute hasSelectAll and set the value to false.
After the first step, the only way that i’ve found throught the API, is to add a logic with the isCreatable attribute.

[react-multi-select-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-select-component)

From my point of view, if you want to use a single selection, i wouldn’t rather use a multi selection library to make it a single selection, instead i would look for some library that makes my work easier.

Answer (score 0):

#### MultiSelect react dropdown let you add a selection limit by adding `selectionLimit={SELECTION_LIMIT}`

So you have to add it like that:

```
<MultiSelect
   selectionLimit={1}
   options={options}
   selected={selected}
   onChange={setSelected}
   labelledBy={"Select"}
/>
```

##### Resources

- For more info about selection limit Take a look [here](https://multiselect-react-dropdown.vercel.app/?path=/story/multiselect-dropdown--selection-limit)
- You can also see other useful options from the official page [here](https://multiselect-react-dropdown.vercel.app/)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple, actually.  Just truncate the `selected` values before they are passed back into the component.  A simple feature like this should be available out of the box.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { MultiSelect } from "react-multi-select-component";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const options = [
    { label: "Grapes ", value: "grapes" },
    { label: "Mango ", value: "mango" },
    { label: "Strawberry ", value: "strawberry" },
    { label: "Watermelon ", value: "watermelon" },
    { label: "Pear ", value: "pear", disabled: true },
    { label: "Apple ", value: "apple" },
    { label: "Tangerine ", value: "tangerine" },
    { label: "Pineapple ", value: "pineapple" },
    { label: "Peach ", value: "peach" }
  ];

  let [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  if (selected.length > 1) {
    selected = selected.slice(1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Select Fruits</h1>
      <MultiSelect
        options={options}
        value={selected}
        onChange={setSelected}
        labelledBy={"Select"}
        isCreatable={true}
        hasSelectAll={false}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set singleSelect to true like singleSelect="true"

```
 <MultiSelect
        displayValue="title"
        onSelect={function noRefCheck(e) {
              setAddPrice({... addPrice, category: e})
        options={categories}
        placeholder="Select category"
        selectedValues={addPrice?.category}
        singleSelect="true"
                                        
 />
```